# Gravitational force due to a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

The question is: What is the direction and the magnitude of the gravitational force exerted on the point-like object of mass  m?

[image: This]

I've tried it like this:
The force between mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ with $r$ distance is $G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$. I split the $2M$ mass into lot of little parts, with mass $M\frac{dx}{2l}$, and distance with $l+dx$, so got the force like this: $$F=\frac{GmM}{l}*\frac{dx}{l^2+2ldx+dx^2}$$

So, where did I make the mistake? Or how could I solve it?

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): Consider to provide a more informative title. Half of the questions on Phys.SE are about writing down an equation.

Comment: Could you give me a more informative + short title?

Answer (score 2):

The expression you have is not $F$ but rather a small force $dF$ which you will need to integrate over the length of your source mass distributions.

Already there are problems with your setup though as each rod produces a net force in a different direction, so you really need to integrate $dF_x$ and $dF_y$ separately, and then add the resulting $F_x\hat x$ and $F_y\hat y$.

Moreover, your written expression for $F$ is incorrect.  The location of a small amount $dM$ of mass for the rod on then horizontal axis, for instance, is $x$ so your
$$
dF_x \propto \frac{dM}{x^2}, \quad dM=\frac{2M}{2\ell}dx
$$
and $dx$ running from $\ell$ to $3\ell$.

Comment: I would calculate the vertical rod's vertical force, and the horizontal rod's horizontal force, and sum them. What does "=∝" mean?

Comment: @user145014 $\propto$ means proportional to.

Comment: @user145014 You wouldn't sum them.  They act in orthagonal directions; so the forces can't be summed together directly.  If you wanted a magnitude of the total force it would be $F_{total} = \sqrt{F_x^2 + F_y^2}$

Comment: @JMac There are three sums here: two integrals and the vector sum of the orthogonal components.

Comment: @JMac I'd sum them as 2 vector, not 2 scalar.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What do you mean?  You would have to do integrals to find $F_x$ and $F_y$.  Summing them would come afterwords.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero could you explain it from the beggining please? I could not get it.

Comment: @user145014 yes of course.  I think JMac just did not notice the unit vectors I had inserted.

Comment: @JMac isn't that just what I described?  We completely agree here.  Maybe what threw you is that I think of an integral as a sum, so the language may have  thrown you off.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I mean the whole equation you got. I'm begginer in this kind of equations.

Comment: Okay, we did agree.  It was the integrals as sums that threw me off, it was accurate; just a bit confusing in the context.  @user145014 sorry I thought you were using $$F=\frac{GmM}{l}*\frac{dx}{l^2+2ldx+dx^2}$$ as the total force.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero so, the force will be $dF_x=G\frac{mdM}{x²}$, and $dM=\frac{2M}{2l}dx$? How did you get the $\frac{dM}{dx}$?

Comment: The M(x) us a constant function, since the density of the rod is constant. So the \$frac{dM}{dx}=0$

Comment: My fault, the $\frac{dM}{dx}$ is the density, which is $\frac{2M}{2l}$. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the right level of hint for a homework-like question.